# How to recursively compare data types of two objects in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to have validation for a class attribute so that it can only take in specific values or specific `type` of values. I've come up with the following approach

```
class someClass:

    value_types = [float, [int], "A", "B"]

    def __init__(self, value):
        for value_type in self.value_types:
            if not self.match_type(value_type, value):
                raise ValueError("The value type is invalid")
        self.value = value

    @staticmethod
    def match_type(obj1, obj2):
         """ 
         For obj1 and obj2 recursively compares all the types of containers and
         elements inside containers, return False in case of mismatch.
         """
         pass
```

I'm trying to find a way of implementing a generic `match_type` function that would work for any kind of `value_type` class attribute. My main motivation behind this is restrict the domain of the instance attribute `value` and validate the values passed based on `value_type` class attribute.

Just for more clarity, the values allowed in the above `someClass` constructor would be

- 7.5
- [1, 9, 8, 6]
- "A"
- "B"

Values for which error should be raised are

- [1.2, 2.3]
- "C"
- []

Comment: It doesn't matter for the purpose of your question, but you have a bunch of bugs in your `__init__` function.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, fixed the bugs.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the type by doing

```
x = 5
type(x) is int
# True
```

however, since you have a weird mix of types and strings, you probably need a more complicated check

```
x = [6, 3]
type(x) is list and type(x[0]) is int
# True

x = 'A'
x == 'A' or x == 'B'
# True
```

what are you trying to accomplish? this is inherently messy

Comment: I'm trying to restrict the domain of a class attribute.

Comment: i guess it's difficult for me to judge without context, but anyway the 3 statements i provide above should be sufficient for your purposes

Comment: Actually I need something generic that can work for all different kinds of `value_types`